# How to solve direct object instantiation warning

Tags: magento2, coding-standards, meqp2

I used following code

```
->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(option_id,' . implode(',', $totalPro).')'));
```

That give following warning.

> Direct object instantiation (object of \Zend_Db_Expr) is discouraged
>   in Magento 2.

How to remove this warning?

Comment: Have you tested:
`->order(\Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(option_id,' . implode(',', $totalPro).')'));`

Magento doesn't use `new \Class\Name` instead of that they have implemented an object manager.

Comment: @DavidVR already tried 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Zend_Db_Expr()`

Comment: @QaisarSatti try first store value in a variable and then use a variable in query. Check this core file: `vendor/magento/module-review/Model/ResourceModel/Rating.php`

Comment: @PrincePatel magento 2 is using `Zend_Db_Expr` but got the same error on core file not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use this :

> \Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\Expression